# What should I use to ping multiple IPs and get notified of time outs?

Tags: software-rec, monitoring, notifications

I've been using [MultiPing](http://www.nessoft.com/multiping/) to ping hundreds of IPs (from access points and such) and check their performance (packet loss, latency) and uptime. The program is very easy to use, but I was wondering if someone could recommend me something that would work better and that would also work in Linux. The features I'm looking for are:

- **Notification Types**: At least **desktop notifications and SMS**, but it would be great if it also had e-mail, IM, or other types of notifications. (MultiPing has some of these, but they don't work too well.)
- **Being notified about the root problem only**: Since some devices are dependent on others, I'd like to be notified only about the root problem. E.g. Let's say I have A[x.x.x.222]>B[x.x.x.33>C[x.x.x.44]>D[x.x.x.55], and B goes down, therefore C and D will also be down. Is it possible to get a notification only about B being down?
- Light on resources.
- Ideally multiplatform or at least available for both Linux and Windows.

I've heard about Nagios and Shinken being used for monitoring. Would you recommend that I use something of the sort or would that be too much for my needs? If using Nagios, Shinken, or similar software is recommended, can anyone tell me what sites I should go to or what books I should get that would be good for someone who is totally new at this?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you're a network administrator. You probably want to check out [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use Nagois.  There are several resources you can use:

1. The nagois website itself.  It has a nice [Documentation](http://www.nagios.org/documentation) section, which will help you with setup and should be able to help you with administration as well
2. [The Nagois Book](http://nagiosbook.org/).  It's a bit outdated, but should still hold true.

Hope this helps!